# Vaadin OSGI application URL access issue

Tags: osgi, vaadin, vaadin7, tomcat8

I have created a Vaadin OSGI bundle using Vaadin 7 and Equinox ServletBridge (Tomcat 8.0). I am able to successfully deploy the bundle in bridge container and status in osgi environment is coming as ACTIVE but I am not able to access my Vaadin application. Not able to understand what URL has to be registered in HTTP Servlet registration.

Default URL for application in Tomcat is working fine (http://localhost:8080/VaadinOsgiApp/servlet/com.example.vaadinosgiapp.VaadinosgiappUI$Servlet)
but in OSGI it's not working.
Any other specific URL to be mapped or to be registered?

PFB respective class code

/** ACTIVATOR CLASS */

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

private ServiceTracker httpServiceTracker;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    httpServiceTracker = new HttpServiceTracker(context);
    httpServiceTracker.open();
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    httpServiceTracker.close();
    httpServiceTracker = null;
}

private class HttpServiceTracker extends ServiceTracker {

    public HttpServiceTracker(BundleContext context) {
        super(context, HttpService.class.getName(), null);
    }

    public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
        HttpService httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(reference);
        try {           
            httpService.registerResources("/*", "/*", null); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            httpService.registerServlet("/*", new VaadinosgiappUI.Servlet(), null, null); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return httpService;
    }       

    public void removedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service) {
        HttpService httpService = (HttpService) service;
        httpService.unregister("/*"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        httpService.unregister("/*"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        super.removedService(reference, service);
    }
}
```

}

/** VAADIN CLASS **/

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("vaadinosgiapp")
public class VaadinosgiappUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = VaadinosgiappUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);

    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(button);
    }
```

}

Comment: Please post your code as code and not as screenshots, they are unreadable

Comment: I have added code instead of Screenshots now